# In theory (because light can still enter a black hole) if you are inside of the event horizon, could you see outside of it?

Tags: visible-light, black-holes, photons, event-horizon

To my limited knowledge, it should be possible for you to see from inside of a black hole. Is this true, or am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/436274, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26185

Comment: @NiharKarve Thank you! When I was writing my title, the first link you put popped up. I assumed their title meant that they were asking whether you would be able to see further into the black hole once inside the event horizon. I examined this post closer, and found out that it actually does have a similar topic to mine. Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: and see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/82678/does-someone-falling-into-a-black-hole-see-the-end-of-the-universe?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you should be able to see out of a black hole, assuming you're still alive.

Comment: "*Yes, you should be able to see out of a black hole*" - According to... your personal opinion as an anonymous user? This site is supposed to be about the established science, not a forum for exchanging personal opinions with no basis. This is a low quality answer not up to the standards of this site.

Comment: The wording of the question asked requires a answer that is a 'yes' or 'no'. It does not ask about the structure of the black hole inside the event horizon or anything else. It does not ask what would an image from outside would look like. There is no minimum word length to an answer. It is also not an unreasonable question as it stands. It simply confirms that light can get in but not out. That is not personal opinion and does not justify a personal attack. I point out that your profile is even more 'anonymous' than mine.

Comment: The purpose of a constructive criticism is to help you improve your answers. Responding with hardminded excuses is pointless. Once again, "yes or no" is an opinion. This site is for science, not opinions. The proper answer here is "yes, because..." or "no, because...".

Comment: I do agree with @shaunokane001's point, and I do agree with what he is saying, but I would like a bit more information. My question may not have been worded to fit this, and if it is not, then I am sorry, but I was asking if you would be able to see directly outside or not. I am aware that light can only enter a black hole, but I am also aware that light bends and has strange behavior around Black Holes. I have limited knowledge, so I am not sure whether this is answerable, or if the answer is true for all Black Holes, but would you be able to see directly out, or would you see a mess of light

Comment: @shaunokane001 A more neutral comment would be: Do you have a reference for this statement?