# Black Holes should take infinite time to form with the increase in mass to form one

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

How can black hole form because as the density begins to increase gravity also start to increase and time starts to slow. wouldn't it take infinite time to form a black hole. how can anything fall beyond event horizon of black hole. if the time completely stops after event horizon. how do black hole gain mass if the object just hangs in event horizon. at event horizon if people got stuck there will he see the end of the universe?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21319/, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79054/