# Would you reach a singularity before evaporation of the black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, time-dilation, singularities, hawking-radiation

When going to a physics camp the other day, we discussed the Schwarzchild-metric for a rotational symmetric non-spinning black hole and its famous time-dilation properties.

However, we know that black holes, after really quite a while, begin to evaporate and eventually disappear completely. Now, given that as you get closer and closer to the singularity, your time dilation with respect to the outsider's reference frame increases unboundedly - could it be possible for the blackhole to completely evaporate before you actually reach the singularity?

Would this not be true for ALL matter which falls into a blackhole?

Comment: It is outsider reference frame, in which fall into bh is unbound. Think of it as everlasting picture of miserable falling observer. In falling observer frame it took rather very short time in comparison to fall inside singularity. So basically your question mixed two reference frames, because you asking about reaching singularity, which suggests you are asking about failing observer, which gets there rather quickly in comparison to evaporation time, measured by external observer!

Comment: also https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/79054/can-matter-really-fall-through-an-event-horizon