# Does it really take an infinite time to reach a Black Hole's event Horizon?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, time-dilation, event-horizon, observers

Does it really take an infinite time to reach a Black Hole's event Horizon.
The forumla for gravitaional time dialation is.
$$t_0=t_1\sqrt{1-r_s/r}$$
So I used wolfram alpha to calculate the time that it would take from the perspecitve of distant observer for an object falling from infinity take to appear to travel from 3 times the raidus of the event horizon to the event horizon.

[https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r%3D%281%2C3%29%2C∫%28%281%2Fr%29%5E.5%2B1%29*1%2F%281-1%2Fr%29%5E.5+dr](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r%3D%281%2C3%29%2C%E2%88%AB%28%281%2Fr%29%5E.5%2B1%29*1%2F%281-1%2Fr%29%5E.5+dr)

And I get a finite value. What's wrong here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can matter really fall through an event horizon?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79054/)

Comment: It doesn't answer it at all.